# Did the makers of Universal Soldier (1992) pay anything to Buffy Saint-Marie, who wrote the song "Universal Soldier"?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, universal-soldier

In 1992, TriStar Pictures released the movie *[Universal Soldier](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105698/)*, about cyborgs created from the bodies of soldiers killed during the Vietnam War. This is a follow-up to [my earlier question here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227221/why-was-the-1992-film-universal-soldier-given-that-title), making this only the second question about this film franchise.

[image: Universal soldiers]

Although the metaphor of the "universal soldier"—the soldier who could be anyone, or everyone, who fought it a war—was older, it was quite obscure until it was used as the title of a song by [Buffy Saint-Marie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffy_Sainte-Marie) in 1963 and became a hit for [Donovan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donovan) in 1965.

Between then and 1992, the name was overwhelmingly associated with the song.  This made me curious whether the filmmakers paid Saint-Marie anything for the reuse of the title.

Comment: Not an answer, since I can't point to evidence, but typically it's very hard to make a copyright claim on a title using normal words, moreso if it's a pre-existing phrase (no matter how obscure).  A title could theoretically be trademarked, but it would be hard to apply a music trademark to a motion picture, and I'm not sure anyone would normally bother.

Comment: Why would they? There are some phrases that are the title of hundreds of songs, nobody has any expectation that the "first user" be paid by the next 999.

Comment: If this were the case I don't we would have [The Patriot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Patriot_(1998_film)) and [The Patriot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Patriot_(2000_film))

Answer (score 3):

### “Universal Soldier” is not protectable IP

First, short phrases do not get [copyright](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/2003/09/09/copyright_protection_for_short/) protection.

Second, trademark protection only arises if there is a reasonable risk of confusion that the goods and services of the infringer (the movie)can be confused as being associated with the trademark holder (the song) when used in trade or commerce.

Third, ideas are not protected by IP laws.

Since, there is no obligation on the movie makers to pay the songwriter, there’s no reason why they would.

Comment: Right. Did the makers of the movies *I, Robot" or "Total Recall* pay anything to the authors who first used those titles? Did Ralph Ellison pay H. G. Wells for "Invisible Man"?

Comment: @user14111 quite possibly they did, at least for "I, Robot", though that will have been for the story premise and ideas rather than the title. "Total Recall" is famously based on "Do androids dream of electric sheep", so not the same title. A novelization of the movie was written, presumably with permission from the film copyright owners, but I think this was after the movie was released.

Comment: 'I, Robot' wasn't even original with Asimov - it was the title of a 1939 story by Eando Binder.

Comment: @bob1 "Total Recall" is based on "We Can Remember It for You Wholesale." It was "Bladerunner" that was based on "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep."

Comment: @Legion600 true, I knew there was something wrong with my statement as I wrote it, but didn't think to check. The point still stands though.

Comment: @GordonD I didn't know that; i'll have to check the story out.

Comment: @bob1 In my comment that you replied too, I was asking whether Otto ("Eando") Binder (or his heirs) received payment from the movie production (or from Asimov's publishers for that matter) for the title "I, Robot", and whether Kenneth Bulmer was compensated for the title "Total Recall".

Comment: @user14111 I doubt it, unless the film plot was in some way related to the story by Bulmer. You can't readily copyright a phrase, because they aren't considered to be distinctive enough.

Comment: Eando Binder was the pen-name of brothers Earl and Otto Binder (E and O, geddit?). In his autobiography Asimov says that his publisher suggested the title "I, Robot". Asimov pointed out that it had already been used by Eando Binder, and the publisher replied, "F*** Eando Binder!"